# Grid from SAGA natural neighbor results in black grid

Tags: qgis, saga, contour, terrain

I'm new in QGIS and I'm following tutorials mainly on YouTube so I created a path in Google Earth then exported to kml which is converted to txt via GPS visualizer.
When added delimited layer it shows just fine but when used SAGA raster creation and Natural neighbor it run without errors but the grid that comes as result is black.

[image]

How do I convert the map to 3d contour to get terrain?

I tried to change options and settings but didn't help.

Comment: What was the input for the SAGA gridding? Did you try running Grid (inverse distance to a power) on the same data? How do you know there's no data there? Maybe it's a display issue. In the Layer Styling panel, what values do you have for min/max, and what settings do you have for Min/Max Value Settings? Put a screen grab in your question. There isn't much information in your question :-)

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJm9lewzooU&ab_channel=GeospatialInformationHub and when performed from minute 5 to 5:39 I got black polygon.

Path is created in Google Eart , exported to kml, in GPS visualiser conveted to txt. Added as delimited layer in QGIS which imports just fine.

Comment: Maybe you have no altitude data. Can you see the points from the CSV file? Can you open the attribute table and check if the data are correct? Take a screenshot and include it in your question.

Comment: It dint allow me to edit.. here is additional info:

I did play with Layer panel and was changing options for min an d max but nothing happen. Txt file has longitude, latitude, elevation.

Print screen with layer https://ibb.co/Hpw8nt0

If I dont use SAGA and use contour then I got terrain with values https://ibb.co/hD7FS5w This means that point with elevation works.
Thank you for reply

Comment: I don't use SAGA much. Can I suggest you use SRTM data instead. It is already a DEM raster. You can resample it as required (it has a 30m grid interval). Apologies if you already know this!

Comment: You just helped me. I used SRTm and I will work with this as I got my results.

than you